# How to best automate report extraction from Vimeo Analytics?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I would like to automate the extract of Vimeo Analytics data.  I see no option in the Vimeo API.  The only option appears to be manual report downloads via the Web Browser.  Is using a tool like Selenium to automate the browser interaction my only option?